# Manipulating configuration properties in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm looking for a way to manipulate `@ConfigurationProperties` defined on initialization so that when I `@Inject / @Autorwired` the configured object using a `@Bean` method it is properly configured.

Scenario:

I have a bunch of properties set in a `.yml` file. Because all of these properties match as Strings some of them need special handling to be properly configured to their respective types (some of them are enums). Do I make my properties object a `@Component` then inject it into the `@Bean` method and modify it? I tried to combine `@Bean` and `@ConfigurationProperties` annotations but the object is configured AFTER the `@Bean` method itself returns, so any manipulation is lost/impossible. What is the best way to do this?

Example:
In my `.yml` i have this:

```
properties:
  sports:
    "football": ["Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 3"]
    "basketball": ["Team 4", "Team 5", "Team 6"]
  settings:
    "football":
      "period1": "45"
      "period2": "90"
      "players": "11"
    "basketball":
      "periods": "4"
      "players": "5"
```

And these match with the following objects:

```
Map<SportsEnum, List<TeamsEnum>
Map<SportsEnum, Map<SportSettingsEnum, String>>
```

TL;DR:
I want to take an object configured from a `.yml/.properties` file and manipulate its injectable representation. Please provide concrete example!

Comment: Spring will do the conversion for you, you don't need to do manual munging. String to enum is supported out-of-the-box just specify the correct enum name/value.

Comment: hmm it doesn't seem to work for me though :S. Note that the configuration is of `Map<EnumKey, List<EnumValue>>` or even `Map<EnumKey1, Map<EnumKey2, EnumValue>>`

Comment: Ah but that is a whole different beast and goes beyond the basic conversion support (you might want to add that to your question...). With a sample of your `.yml` and what you expect in java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is definitely supported, my guess is that you're doing something wrong. Let's go step by step.

First, your YAML file is badly formatted, it should look something like this:

```
properties:
  sports:
    football:
      - Team1
      - Team2
      - Team3
    basketball:
      - Team4
      - Team5
      - Team6
  settings:
    football:
      period1: 45
      period2: 90
      players: 11
    basketball:
      periods: 4
      players: 5
```

Then, your configuration properties would look like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "properties", locations = "classpath:sports.yml")
public class SportsProperties {

    private Map<SportsEnum, List<TeamsEnum>> sports;
    private Map<SportsEnum, Map<SportSettingsEnum, String>> settings;

    public Map<SportsEnum, List<TeamsEnum>> getSports() {
        return sports;
    }

    public void setSports(Map<SportsEnum, List<TeamsEnum>> sports) {
        this.sports = sports;
    }

    public Map<SportsEnum, Map<SportSettingsEnum, String>> getSettings() {
        return settings;
    }

    public void setSettings(
        Map<SportsEnum, Map<SportSettingsEnum, String>> settings) {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void customManipulation() {
        System.out.println(sports);
        System.out.println(settings);
    }
}
```

Next, the properties should be enabled in your configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SportsProperties.class)
public class YamlSampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(YamlSampleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

That should be it, really. Here are my enums:

```
public enum SportsEnum {
    football, basketball
}

public enum TeamsEnum {
    Team1, Team2, Team3, Team4, Team5, Team6
}

public enum SportSettingsEnum {
    periods, period1, period2, players
}
```

Here's the output I get in the logs:

```
2016-07-26 17:44:41.226 DEBUG 30015 --- [           main] s.b.e.YamlPropertySourceLoader$Processor : Loading from YAML: class path resource [sports.yml]
2016-07-26 17:44:41.282 DEBUG 30015 --- [           main] s.b.e.YamlPropertySourceLoader$Processor : Matched document with default matcher: {properties={sports={football=[Team1, Team2, Team3], basketball=[Team4, Team5, Team6]}, settings={football={period1=45, period2=90, players=11}, basketball={periods=4, players=5}}}}
2016-07-26 17:44:41.282 DEBUG 30015 --- [           main] s.b.e.YamlPropertySourceLoader$Processor : Loaded 1 document from YAML resource: class path resource [sports.yml]
{football=[Team1, Team2, Team3], basketball=[Team4, Team5, Team6]}
{football={period1=45, period2=90, players=11}, basketball={periods=4, players=5}}
```

Comment: This is solves my problem of HAVING to configure the properties but it doesn't answer the specific question and I can't mark it as an answer. Thanks for your insight however.

Comment: Doesn't it? You just need to put whatever modifications you want into the `@PostConstruct` method. Though I now see that I've never mentioned this in the answer :)

Comment: Indeed I didn't think about that.

Comment: Is there a way to make this `@PostConstruct` stuff work for inner classes? (The parent class has the `ConfigurationProperties` annotation already)

Comment: @takanuva15 `@PostConstruct` can only work on objects managed by Spring (beans, configurations, configuration properties, etc). If your inner class isn't managed by Spring, then it won't work